# Select Where Like regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I need to create a SQL Query.
This query need to select from a table where a column contains regular expression.

For example, I have those values:

TABLE test (name)

- XHRTCNW
- DHRTRRR
- XHRTCOP
- CPHCTPC
- CDDHRTF
- PEOFOFD

I want to select all the data who have "HRT" after 1 char (value 1, 2 and 3 - Values who looks like "-HRT---") but not those who might have "HRT" after 1 char (value 5).

So I'm not sure how to do it because a simple

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE name LIKE "%HRT%"
```

will return value 1, 2, 3 and 5.

Sorry if I'm not really clear with what I want/need.

Comment: plsql is for Oracle only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring`.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE substring(name from 2 for 3) = 'HRT'
```

Comment: Cool ! It's working with this function. Is there any link where I can find "All the function" available in the Where section?

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the pattern.  Instead of using `%` which means zero-or-more anything, you can use `_` which means exactly one.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name like '_HRT%';
```

Comment: Oh, this way is also working thanks ! Is there any other char that might means other value than "_" ?

Comment: The LIKE function is quite restricted and only uses "_" and "%" as wildcards.  There are other functions available that do full regular expression matching etc.   Details available at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0):

Are the names always 7 letters? Do:

```
SELECT substring (2, 4, field) from sometable
```

That will just select the 2-4th characters and then you can use like "%HRT"

Comment: Nop sadly, it's not always 7 letters

Comment: Regardless, all three answers will return the entries you are looking for.